# Pylint and Subprocess.Run returning Exit Status 28

Tags: subprocess, python-3.5, pylint

I'm trying to run pylint using subprocess but getting a vague message stating non-zero exit status 28. I can not find any reference to an exit status 28 for either Pylint or subprocess.

I can only assume this is a pylint/windows issue as running some other typical commands e.g. head, works just fine as does running pylint directly in the console.

Running python 3.5 on Windows 10.

Any ideas?

**MWE**

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'pylint test_script.py'
subprocComplete = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(subprocComplete.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

**Output**

```
python35 pylint_subprocess_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pylint_subprocess_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocComplete = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 708, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'pylint test_script.py' returned non-zero exit status 28
```

Comment: pylint returns nonzero if it finds any niggle with the file it examines. if you run pylint from the command line what does it say?

Comment: It runs fine from the command line; normal output with the various types C,W,R etc. Finishes with a code rating.

Comment: OK, I think my brain has finally allowed the pieces to fall in to place for me: if any message type is encountered, an exit status will be returned as per the --long-help output status code although this does not contain an entry for exit code 28. I'd really like a method to sub-process pylint and receive the full output as per the standard command line usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the subprocess returns nonzero (which pylint often will), then `subprocComplete` never gets assigned to. You can catch the error, and the error object holds the output you want.

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'pylint test_script.py'
try:
    subprocComplete = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(subprocComplete.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    print(err.output.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you Colonel. I had been using err.decode('utf-8')